# How to use http for subdomain when domain uses https in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have a basic configuration in my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com` file that redirects HTTP traffic to the HTTPS version of a site.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl on;
  ... rest of the site configuration
}
```

The above is working fine. When I visit http://example.com, I'm redirected to https://example.com.

I need a sub domain on example.com, but it only needs HTTP.  I created an `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sub.example.com` file that starts with

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name sub.example.com;
```

At first, it appeared to work, but I noticed a problem:

1. Clear out the browser cache and visit http://sub.example.com.  The site comes up without any problems.
2. Next, visit http://example.com. The browser is redirected to
   https://example.com which is good.
3. Go back and visit http://sub.example.com again.  **This time, the browser is redirected to https://sub.example.com and the browser complains about a missing cert.**

Why is this happening?  What is the proper way to use HTTP for a subdomain, but HTTPS on the domain?

Comment: Do you have HSTS? - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Comment: I'm 99% sure you have `includeSubDomains` directive in your HSTS header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@alexey-ten was correct. In my particular case, I had followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04 tutorial for using LetsEncrypt to obtain the cert.  During the tutorial I created an `ssl-params.conf` file and loaded it into my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com` file with

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl on;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf;
  ... rest of the site configuration
}
```

Sure enough the ssl-params.conf file had the following line:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
```

Removing `includeSubdomains` and restarting the server got things working the way I expected.